# How to edit a json file using jsoncons?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncons

I am using [jsoncons](https://github.com/danielaparker/jsoncons), which is a requirement for this question.

I am trying to edit some fields in a deeply nested json file, for example the following one:

```
{
    "Error": null,
    "HubNotificationId": "8a321f40-3692-11ec-b2a8-02420a0000fc",
    "HubNotificationTimestamp": "2021-10-26T19:25:55.330812",
    "MessageTimestampUtc": "2021-10-26T19:25:55",
    "Result": "SUCCESS",
    "ScanId": "0789e64f-87a7-42b0-a912-362acad7536c",
    "ScanTimestampUtc": "2021-10-26T19:25:44",
    "Source": {
        "InstanceId": "",
        "ModuleId": "atlas",
        "ServiceId": "uv-acquisition-manager",
        "ServiceVersion": "2.1.0-0001",
        "SiteId": "rnd-oem-holon"
    },
    "Type": "ScanNotification",
    "Version": "2.8.0",
    "abortReason": null,
    "context": "scan/end",
    "data": [
        {
            "frameGrabberId": "at-uv-dm-fg1",
            "scanLocation": {
                "Original_ScaledDown": {
                    "keyPrefix": null,
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Original_ScaledDown",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                },
                "Undistorted_ScaledDown": {
                    "keyPrefix": null,
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Undistorted_ScaledDown",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                },
                "Unprocessed": {
                    "keyPrefix": "a0366334-b44b-459e-8484-8a0c835c6889/c5424457-9066-4d82-9ab9-df5cc2a17c21/20201006/2020-10-06T11-16-04.000Z_98021622-12ff-455b-972d-79af24c169a1",
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Unprocessed",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "frameGrabberId": "at-uv-dm-fg2",
            "scanLocation": {
                "Original_ScaledDown": {
                    "keyPrefix": null,
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Original_ScaledDown",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                },
                "Undistorted_ScaledDown": {
                    "keyPrefix": null,
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Undistorted_ScaledDown",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                },
                "Unprocessed": {
                    "keyPrefix": "INJECTED",
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Unprocessed",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "frameGrabberId": "at-uv-dm-fg3",
            "scanLocation": {
                "Original_ScaledDown": {
                    "keyPrefix": null,
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Original_ScaledDown",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                },
                "Undistorted_ScaledDown": {
                    "keyPrefix": null,
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Undistorted_ScaledDown",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                },
                "Unprocessed": {
                    "keyPrefix": "a0366334-b44b-459e-8484-8a0c835c6889/c5424457-9066-4d82-9ab9-df5cc2a17c21/20201006/2020-10-06T11-16-04.000Z_98021622-12ff-455b-972d-79af24c169a1",
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Unprocessed",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "frameGrabberId": "at-uv-dm-mgr",
            "scanLocation": {
                "Original_ScaledDown": {
                    "keyPrefix": null,
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Original_ScaledDown",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                },
                "Undistorted_ScaledDown": {
                    "keyPrefix": null,
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Undistorted_ScaledDown",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                },
                "Unprocessed": {
                    "keyPrefix": "a0366334-b44b-459e-8484-8a0c835c6889/c5424457-9066-4d82-9ab9-df5cc2a17c21/20201006/2020-10-06T11-16-04.000Z_98021622-12ff-455b-972d-79af24c169a1",
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "role": "Unprocessed",
                    "uri": "INJECTED"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "dynamicMetaData": {
        "vehicleParams": {
            "color": "122",
            "model": "225",
            "vendor": "a"
        }
    },
    "scanDuration_sec": 10.98,
    "shotsCount": 96,
    "sourceInfo": [],
    "staticMetaData": null
}
```

I want to edit some of the keys - for example, the `uri` keys.

How to use the library to be able to edit the json and save an edited copy?

What I have so far is

```
    const jsoncons::json& TestMessage::injectPathToFMTemplate(const std::string &scanPath) {
        auto& raw = this->_raw_input;
        auto& parsed = this->_templateMessage;
        auto parsedTree = parsed.as<std::map<std::string, jsoncons::json>>();
        auto dataPos = parsedTree.find("data");
        auto& data = dataPos->second;
        auto grabbers = data.as<std::vector<std::map<std::string, jsoncons::json>>>();
        int grabberIndex = 0;
        for (auto& grabberTree : grabbers){
            auto scanLocationPos = grabberTree.find("scanLocation");
            auto scanLocationTree = scanLocationPos->second.as<std::map<std::string, jsoncons::json>>();

            auto Original_ScaledDownPos = scanLocationTree.find("Original_ScaledDown");
            auto Undistorted_ScaledDownPos = scanLocationTree.find("Undistorted_ScaledDown");
            auto UnprocessedPos = scanLocationTree.find("Unprocessed");
            auto Original_ScaledDownPosTree = Original_ScaledDownPos->second.as<std::map<std::string, jsoncons::json>>();
            auto Undistorted_ScaledDownPosTree = Original_ScaledDownPos->second.as<std::map<std::string, jsoncons::json>>();
            auto UnprocessedPosTree = Original_ScaledDownPos->second.as<std::map<std::string, jsoncons::json>>();

            auto uriPos1 = Original_ScaledDownPosTree.find("uri");
            auto uriPos2 = Undistorted_ScaledDownPosTree.find("uri");
            auto uriPos3 = UnprocessedPosTree.find("uri");

            uriPos1->second = scanPath;
            uriPos2->second = scanPath;
            uriPos3->second = scanPath;

            ++grabberIndex;
        }

        parsed = jsoncons::json(parsedTree);
        auto s = parsed.as<std::string>();
        return parsed;
```

Which goes all the way down to the `uri` fields, but then can't edit them because nothing is (or can be) by reference, and I find that I have to re-build all of the json object again, which makes no sense.

I am sure the library allows this somehow, just can't find out how.

Comment: from a quick scan through the documentation it doesn't seem like your use of `as` is necessary, just keep objects as `jsoncons::json`

Comment: @AlanBirtles I also read the documentation, and was not able to do what I needed. Can you please show code?

Answer (score 0):

The jsoncons library provides a number of options for editing a JSON value, but a simple way is

```
std::string scanPath = "FOO";

try
{
    json root = json::parse(input);
    json& data = root.at("data");

    for (auto& grabberTree : data.array_range())
    {
        json& scanLocationTree = grabberTree.at("scanLocation");

        json& Original_ScaledDown = scanLocationTree.at("Original_ScaledDown");

        json& Undistorted_ScaledDown = scanLocationTree.at("Undistorted_ScaledDown");

        json& Unprocessed = scanLocationTree.at("Unprocessed");

        Original_ScaledDown.at("uri") = scanPath;
        Undistorted_ScaledDown.at("uri") = scanPath;
        Unprocessed.at("uri") = scanPath;
    }

    std::cout << pretty_print(root) << "\n";
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << "\n";
}
```